# Linux Terminal for SSH into Windows Machine

Tags: linux, ssh, terminal

I have a remote server that's running Windows and uses MINGW64 when I log into it with ssh from my local machine, the terminal doesn't behave correctly, for instance:

- Can't backspace
- If output from a command is too much, the terminal will stop showing anything at all
- Some commands output an error message about being incompatible with rxvt-unicode

I've tried using: xterm, gnome-terminal, and rxvt-unicode, but all of them have the same issues.

So to reiterate, my question is: is there a way on Ubuntu I can get my terminal to be more compatible with the remote server which is using MINGW64 (shows as `user@host MINGW64 /path/to/pwd (master)`?

Edit: To clarify, I'm on Ubuntu Linux and the remote machine is using Windows 10, with MINGW as the shell that opens with SSH.

Comment: If you have Windows10 and above, I recommend you try [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/about) which should be much more Linux compatible than MINGW64.

Comment: @aviro I'd recommend the same, but it's not clear to me if the OP *controls* the remote Windows machine or is just a user on it.  If they do control it, I do recommend WSL, but I'd still recommend Windows OpenSSH server (built in to Windows as well) as the SSH interface to WSL.